# Using graphical ActiveX (COM) controls in WinForms project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2005, activex

I have a collection (set) of ActiveX controls. I recieved them from our vendor company.

I created a wrappers for them using tlbimp.exe and aximp.exe.

All non-graphical controls work good.

All graphical controls don't react on some methods. When I call their methods I get:

TargetInvocativeException (InnerException is null).
or
Attempt to read/write protected memory.

Our vendor company assure that their graphical activex controls work good. But they don't provide support service, so I have to find solution of my problem alone.

And some more,

All graphical activex controls don't react on mouseclick or any other mouse manipulations. But documentation says: it must change the color on mouse click.

**Maybe, someone have same symptoms and can help me** ! I googled over that problem many pages but they don't help me.

Maybe it's some Visual Studio settings or compiler options ? I use VS 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work at all? Try [ActiveX Control Test Container (tstcon32.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241446(VS.80).aspx) .

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I think that something wrong with my activex controls. Thanks for a link tsccon32.exe anyway :)